# outlook forms Vb script update field value

Tags: forms, vbscript, outlook

I have a custom form in outlook 2013 one of the fields is called "LoggedBy" and needs to store user name of the person who makes the calendar entry now I can get this to work via the following code when I test it using "run this code" however when i publish it to shared calendar servicedeskcallback it does not display anything or store it.  Code below is designed to work as the form is open it should display name and write it to the field.

```
Function Item_Open()
    Fullname = Left(Application.Session.CurrentUser.Name,instr(Application.Session.CurrentUser.Name, "(")-2)
    Lastname = Left(Fullname,instr(Fullname," ")-1)
    Firstname = Right(fullname,instr(fullname," ")+1)
    Item.UserProperties.Find("LoggedBy").value = Firstname & " " & Lastname
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

Your appointment form needs to have a control that is bound to the custom field you've created in order for it to automatically populate with the data you are storing in the field via code.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was caused because the following options where not checked in outlook under trusted center e-mail security\Allow scripts in shared folders.

thanks for all your help  Eric Legault